# How to fix scaling issue on mobile for simple html/css website

Tags: html, css, mobile

I recently created a website in order to serve as a portfolio of sorts for any future projects that I complete during University. I self-taught myself Html/CSS to create the web-page so obviously the code itself is probably pretty poor quality. I'll probably be creating a new website when I learn React.js, but for now this is what I have.

The link is: https://etnwang.github.io/

The files can be found at https://github.com/eTNwang/eTNwang.github.io

I think the page looks decent on a desktop, but it completely breaks apart on mobile. I did my best to utilize percentages of width and height whenever possible and vh instead of px. However, it still looks horrendous. I added the line

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but it didn't do anything for the site.

Anyone have any idea how to fix the mobile scaling issue?

On desktop:

looks decent:

[image]

On mobile:

terribleness

[image]

Comment: Have you used any media tags? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp Normally you set the blocks on your page to be like 100% width, when the window is less than 600px for example

Comment: I didn't use any media tags, and I also set my divs to have widths based on percentage ex: width: 40%

Comment: I highly suggest adding [mediaqueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a nice setup at start, where you position your elements in two different blocks with flex. Nameblock as 60% width and your imgage with 40% width. However this gets really small on mobile. I would reccomend in  your case to add a different flex direction when the window gets smaller than 600px (for example). And then also change your padding left as you want to position the image.

```
@media (max-width:600px){ 
    .flex-container {
     flex-direction: column;
  }
.img img{ 
     padding-left: 15vh;
  } 
.nameblock{
     width:90%;
     margin: auto;
     padding-left:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the super helpful advice, I'll definitely give the media query. Do you know what might be causing the current mobile layout to be so hideous? I know that my friend's websites all resize themselves into a smaller version on mobile. Is there a reason why mine doesn't display the same behavior ?

Comment: Hard to say without looking to be honest, depends on how he wrote the code, he could also be using a templete or something

Comment: sounds good, implemented your suggestions w/ @media calls and the site is already looking fantastic. Thanks for all the advice!

Comment: no worries, dont forget to check the answer if it helped you:)